# Dynamic audio file import in react is causing page reload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to reproduce dynamic audio file with react, but the page reloads everytime the file changes.

**Context:**

I'm sending some text from front-end with Socket.io to my server. There in the server, I am converting text in audio with TextToSpeech Google API then with Node.js I am writing an audio file in front-end's source folder. 
To reproduce this audio in the browser, I import this audio file and then I reproduce it with a button.

**Problem:**

Even with the e.preventDefault() my page reloads after the audio file is created. The funny thing is: when I write the same sentence or word, the browser do not reloads. So I suspect that it renders because of the file change (perhaps because it's forced to re-import?)

When I remove this line:

`import audioFile from './output.ogg';`

and everything that uses 'audioFile', the browser do not reload.

I expect to send my text and reproduce the audio just like Google Translate does!

Comment: It really isn't possible to help you debug when you don't actually show us your code.

Comment: Of-course page will reload in development mode if you change the source files. Your approach of having a dynamic audio file is incorrect. Your server needs to create a create an audio file and save it somewhere which can be accessed using a url. Then on frontend you use `fetch` (or something similar) to load the file, from internet(or localhost server) NOT by changing the source code of React project.

Comment: Alright, I'll post the code soon. And about the approach, I'll try what you're saying. Thank you, guys!